# How can I pass a paramValues from a page to another?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I got an action page receiving a `paramValues.receipt` from a form.
I want to pass this array to another action page by doing

```
<c:set var="receipt1" value="paramValues.receipt"/>
```

apparently it is not working...
Do you guys have any solutions to this?

Comment: Sollution for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set it to the scope wider than a `page`. If the page is included or forwarded with the same request then you can use `request` scope.

```
<c:set var="receipt1" value="paramValues.receipt" scope="request"/>
```